# R Shiny Datatable: prevent deselection of an already selected row when you click on it again

Tags: javascript, r, datatables, shiny, dt

R (ver 3.4.1)
I am working with DT (ver 0.4) package in shiny (ver 1.0.5) and have a need where I want to prevent the deselection of an already selected row when user clicks on it again. For example in below image if user clicks on row 3 again it should not get deselected. However if user selects a new row then that new row gets selected while the earlier row gets deselected.

> I guess what I need is for datatable to completely ignore a
>   click-event on an already selected row.

[image: If user clicks on row 3 again it should not get deselected but if he clicks on a new row then that new row should get selected while deselecting the old one]

I tried using `shinyjs::onclick` as shown below but is not ideal as it seems to *"de-select & re-select"* the selected row (the blue highlight disappears and reappears when clicked on again) rather than **preventing deselection**.

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)
library(shinyjs)

shinyApp(
  ui <- shinyUI(
    fluidPage(
      shinyjs::useShinyjs(),
      DTOutput("test")
    )
  ),  
  server <- shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {

    output$test <- renderDT({
      datatable(head(iris), selection = 'single')
    })    
    shinyjs::onclick("test",
               selectRows(dataTableProxy("test"), selected = input$test_rows_selected)
             )    
  })
)
```

I was wondering if there was an easy way to do this. Thanks!

Comment: Shree, I have edited my first answer to provide a working solution. Say me if it works for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `pointer-events: none` in css:

```
table.dataTable tbody tr.selected {
  pointer-events: none
}
```

The only limitation is it prevents the whole hover/clicking event on the currently selected row, so you can't use it on columns with hoverable/clickable HTML contents.

I hope it helps!

Comment: This is great! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is only a partial solution *(see the **edit** below for a fully working solution)*. It works only when you click twice on the row. At the third click, the row is deselected, I don't know why. Maybe an expert in `datatables` could help.

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)

shinyApp(
  ui <- shinyUI(
    fluidPage(
      DTOutput("test")
    )
  ),  
  server <- shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {

    output$test <- renderDT({
      datatable(head(iris), selection = list(mode="single", target="row"), 
                extensions = c("Select"), options = list(select=TRUE),
                callback = JS("
table.on('user-select', 
function (e, dt, type, cell, originalEvent) {
  if ($(cell.node()).parent().hasClass('selected')) {
    e.preventDefault();
  }
});"))
    })    
  })
)
```

## EDIT

I've found a solution (I don't fully understand it).

```
  server <- shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {

    output$test <- renderDT({
      datatable(head(iris), selection = list(mode="single", target="row", info=FALSE), 
                extensions = c("Select"), options = list(select=TRUE),
                callback = JS("
  table.on('user-select', 
    function (e, dt, type, cell, originalEvent) {
      if ($(cell.node()).parent().hasClass('selected') || e.result === undefined) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(cell.node()).parent().addClass('selected')
        return false;
      }
    });")
      )
    })    
  })
```

Comment: This solution seems to be doing the same thing as mine (using `shinjs::onclick()`) i.e. deselecting first and then re-selecting the clicked row. Am I missing something? I guess what I need is for datatable to completely ignore a click-event on an already selected row. Hope that makes sense. Thanks!

Comment: @Shree I'm not sure the row is deselected at the first click. But it seems that's what happens at the next click. But I'm not sure at all.

Comment: @Shree And you are not satisfied by this way ? Why ? Maybe you should precise what you want to do.